# Many to Many relation for ApplicationUser and Custom model class

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to implement following case scenario:
There is a custom table, let's say Task and I would like to create Many to Many relation with class Application user.

Currently I have following project arcitechture:

```
- Client
- Server
   - ApplicationUser.cs
- Shared
   - Task.cs
```

Here are classes:

Task.cs in Shared assembly:

```
public class Task
{      
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }    
    public List<ApplicationUserTask> ApplicationUserTasks { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser.cs in Server assembly:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }    
    public List<ApplicationUserTask> ApplicationUserTasks { get; set; }
}
```

According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) I need to create a new class called something like:

```
public class ApplicationUserTask
{      
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

There are references for Shared assembly in Client and Server. However due to current structure it is not possible to have such a relation and I need to move `ApplicationUser.cs` class to Shared assembly, but then I am getting conflict with NuGet packages, because of this one `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;`

What should I do?

1. Create new class in Shared assembly? For example UserModel.cs and operate with this one? In this case there would be new table in DB. Should I constantly copy ApplicationUser table to UserModel table then?
2. Move Task.cs to Server assembly do all procedures according to Microsoft documentation and then create TaskDTO.cs to Shared assembly and communicate with Client through DTO model?
3. Some other better option?

I am using: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />`

Comment: What EFCore (implied from linked resource - if incorrect, state correct ORM) version do you use?

Comment: *In this case there would be new table in DB* - typical RDBMS do not support M:M so we decompose into two 1:M. Whether you see this in the C# side depends on EF version and setup

Comment: Side note, having your own class Task sets you up for endless confusion with Threadng.Task. Think of another name.

Comment: @HenkHolterman it was just an example. My real class name is Project.cs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do?

Option 2) is the best, imho.

IdentityUser belongs to a closed library that you don't want to reference in your client. It also contains a lot of fields that you don't need or want to expose in your API.

Your problem comes from an attempt to combine Model and DTO classes. That is not a best practice, although I admit it can be attractive in a (very) small app.

So keep your Models in the Server project and put tailor made DTO classes in Shared. Right now it is only essential for the User class but when your project grows you will be glad you did it for the rest too.

Comment: Alright, so you say Shared should only have so called DTO classes and all actual model classes should be in Server? If so, I need to redo quite some things already. It is my first Blazor app... but it already started to grow quite fast as I thought about real case scenario, where it can be actually used

Comment: Yes. Look at IdentityUser, with the PasswordHash and LockoutStatus etc. You don't want that on the Client. The same will develop for your Task and other Models.

Comment: Can you also guide me a little bit further. Should I use DTO's or there is some other better option like ViewModel's or something else? I mean is it better to go for ViewModel implementation?

Comment: With Blazor you can use the  DTOs as (passive) ViewModels.